# BiilingStreet error on Account insertion programmatically

Tags: account

this is definitely a Salesforce bug, I just wonder if somebody know the root cause:

**Bellow script show error: Field does not exist: BillingStreet  on Account**

```
Account acc = new Account(name = 'GLOBÁL-VÉP KFT.',                            
                      BillingStreet = 'Petőfi út 7.',
                      billingcity = 'DRÉGELYPALÁNK',
                      billingstate = '',
                      billingpostalcode = '2646',                          
                      fax = '36 35 367 067',
                      phone = '36 35 367 302'                        
                     );
upsert acc;
```

but if i comment the second line and do:

```
Account acc = new Account(name = 'GLOBÁL-VÉP KFT.',                            
                      //BillingStreet = 'Petőfi út 7.',
                      billingcity = 'DRÉGELYPALÁNK',
                      billingstate = '',
                      billingpostalcode = '2646',                          
                      fax = '36 35 367 067',
                      phone = '36 35 367 302'                        
                     );

acc.BillingStreet = 'Petőfi út 7.';
upsert acc;
```

**It does work.**
Why?

Comment: Can you give us any error message?

Comment: First one works fine for me via exec anon, what makes you so sure it's a platform bug?

Comment: Error message is written on it:
Bellow script show error: Field does not exist: BillingStreet on Account

this happens when I try to execute above code on the anonymous block

Comment: Works fine for me on CS43, what have you checked that leads you to believe it's a platform bug? This is helpful to others.

Comment: Perhaps there's an invisible character that was included in the "BillingStreet" string (which could happen if you copy/pasted this from somewhere). Can you try typing out that key/value pair manually and see if that works?

Comment: No issues when executing on EU37 by using ctrl c ctrl v directly from the question.

Comment: Just worked in a brand new playground on UM6...(promise not trolling)

Comment: ctrl+c and ctrl+v is precisely what can lead to the issue with invisible characters being copied. Seriously, just try deleting that entire line of code (the one key-value pair) and try typing it out manually.

Comment: apparently there is an invisible character...